# Update to window 8.1 fails with error code 0xC1900101-0x2002000A

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-update, updates

I recently tried to update my computer from Window 8 to Window 8.1.
It got to 83% and just froze. I restarted the computer, and it gave me the error code 0xC1900101-0x2002000A.

I did have windows 8.1, but I had to refresh my computer (reset all apps but keep documents and data). After the refresh, I was back to windows 8 and haven't been able to get windows 8.1 since.

Though I doubt this is the cause, I have my computer set to dual boot windows and Ubuntu

Comment: Did you try [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/error-0xc1900101-0x20017-when-installing-windows/8631668d-1924-4259-8280-494f9f94f8b3)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft says that these errors are very hard to track.

Quote: "Microsoft is aware some customers are unable to install Windows 8.1 due to error 0xC1900101 -0x20017.

This error indicates a failure to boot Windows 8.1 occurred during the initial reboot of the update, causing the system to roll back to Windows 8. The most likely cause of this error is an incompatible driver or hardware defect critical for booting the intermediary environment necessary to perform upgrade actions. Unfortunately, due to the timing of this failure, there are often no logs, crash dumps or other diagnostic information available to investigate the issue easily, which makes it difficult to determine which, if any, of the drivers or system components are causing the update to fail."

Here is a link to more information: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/error-0xc1900101-0x20017-when-installing-windows/8631668d-1924-4259-8280-494f9f94f8b3?auth=1

Comment: I was able to get windows 8.1 a few months ago (it backdated when I refreshed). Why not now?

Comment: @JackMcDowell - Likely has something to do with the fact you used the Refresh feature without upgrading the image, used during the process, thus leading to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try a new refresh again. Back up your data to an external device and rebuild using a new partition. When you have Windows 8 installed, download and apply all critical updates, because you want Windows 8 to be as close to the Windows 8.1 code base to avoid any of the issue that you had experienced.  Check that all is good in Device Manager before attempting it again.

Here is the full steps to go from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial

Comment: If he is going to do this he should use `Reset` instead.  This way the problem is guaranteed to be fixed, I only suggest this, because this answer suggests he backs up his personal files.